# Backup2mail can't send email with database backup..multiple or malformed newlines?

Tags: database-backups

Until 18 June I received all days my backup database on Gmail without problems, I had finally found the solution for this. But after 18 June emails with database are stopped. I don't receive neither normal email with only log file txt..nothing I receive now.

I use Backup2mail http://www.backup2mail.com/

PHP Version 5.6.13, Ubuntu Linux 14.04.1

The database backup file is perfectly created on server but it can't send more to Gmail.

I have this error in index.php file of Backup2mail:

> Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in > /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myappname/public/backuptomail/index.php on line 119
>   Database not sent! Please check your mail settings.
>   Sent? No

On line 119 there is:

```
if (mail($send_to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    $sent = 'Yes';      
    echo ($file_is_db ? 'Backup file' : 'Report') . ' sent to ' . $send_to . '.<br />';
    if ($file_is_db) {
        if ($delete_backup) {
            unlink($file);
            echo 'Backup file REMOVED from disk.<br />';
        } else {
            echo 'Backup file LEFT on disk.<br />';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<span style="color: #f00;">' . ($file_is_db ? 'Database' : 'Report') . ' not sent! Please check your mail settings.</span><br />';
}

echo 'Sent? ' . $sent;
```

Where is the problem? :( Maybe from 18 june PHP is upgraded and changed something? I'm not expert.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a recent update in PHP. Under this update you can no longer have multiple (`\n`) new lines in the header. Thus you need to remove the newlines in a few places.

Find the following lines and remove the trailing \n (leave just one):

```
$body = 'Database backup file:' . "\n" . ' - ' . $file . "\n\n";

$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\n\n";
```

However you also need to remove the \n in the following line as well:

```
$headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode(implode('', file($file)))) . "\n";
```

change it to:

```
$headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode(implode('', file($file)))) . "";
```

It should work after these changes.
Hope this helps you out mate.

Comment: YEs, Bro I have found so many solution but it works... Damd Good.